# jquery name selector not working in ie6

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
var brands = document.getElementsByName("brand");
for(var brand in brands){
    $("input[name='brand']").eq(brand).click(function(){
                        alert("hello22");
                        loadDataFN(1);                
                });
}
```

This code is not executing in ie6,
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is in the variable `brand`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely that you are trying to use a for-in construct to iterate over a numeric array. This often won't give expected results. Use an incremental for loop instead:

```
var brands = document.getElementsByName("brand");

// Use an incremental for loop to iterate an array
for(var i=0; i<brands.length; i++){
    $("input[name='brand']").eq(brands[i]).click(function(){
                        alert("hello22");
                        loadDataFN(1);                
                });
}
```

#### However,

after seeing the first part of your code, the loop appears unnecessary. You should only need the following, since you are assigning the same function to all brand inputs.

```
// These will return the same list of elements (as long as you don't have non-input elements named brand)
// though the jQuery version will return them as jQuery objects
// rather than plain DOM nodes
var brands = document.getElementsByName("brand");
$("input[name='brand']");
```

Therefore, the `getElementsByName()` and loop are not necessary.

```
$("input[name='brand']").click(function() {
       alert("hello22");
       loadDataFN(1);                
});
```

`for-in` loops are used for iterating over the properties of an object, not over the elements of an array.

Comment: Thanks Michael, jQuery is doing its job on its own end. I think! The problem is in other parts of my js code. It worked fine when i moved it to upper section of page.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you write the code without jQuery if this doesn't work?

Something like this:

```
function getInputByName(name) {
    var i, j = document.getElementsByTagName('input').length;

    for(i=0;i<j;++i) { // You can also use getAttribute, but maybe it won't work in IE6
        if(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].name === name) {
            return document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i];
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I don't know jQuery, but maybe you can do something like this:

```
$(getInputByName('brand')).eq(brand).click(function(){
                    alert("hello22");
                    loadDataFN(1);                
            });
```

Comment: Thats a good thing, except this: A lot of people lern how to use frameworks but can't write anything without it.